# How to fetch and display data from two different APIs

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend, display, fetch-api

So I'm learning React and got stuck with fetching data from two different APIs and displaying the data into the same table. I can display data from the first API where I get the number and name but when I try to display data from the second API to get the genre, it won't work anymore. I'm not even sure can I do it this way, but hopefully someone can help.

```
class Stops extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      books: [],
      authors: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/url1')
      .then((res) => {
        res.json()
          .then(data => this.setState({ books: data }))
      })
    fetch('/url2')
      .then((response) => {
        response.json()
          .then(authorData => this.setState({authors: authorData }))
      })
  }
  Displayauthors (authors) {
    return authors.map((author) => (
      <div key={author.authorId}>
         {author.genre}
      </div>
    ))
  }
  render () {
    const books = this.state.books
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>number</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>Genre</th>
              <th>Download book</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
             books.map((book) => (
                <tr key={book.id}>
                  <td>{book.number}</td>
                  <td>{book.name}</td>
                  <td>{this.displayAuthors(this.state.authors)}</td>
                  <td><button type="button">Download</button></td>
               </tr>
             ))
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch the data, but not directly into the state.
Instead create something like a "allStuffLoadedNow" Flag in the state.

### Workflow

If `fetch 1` succeed, it writes the result-data into a local variable (maybe `this.prop.fetchResult1`)
`Fetch 2` does the same to `this.prop.fetchResult2`.

After each `success` (of both fetch-requests), check if the `fetchResult` of the `other` fetch is still done (means you check if `this.prop.fetchResult1!==null` for example).
If it's not `null`, you set the STATE-Variable `allStuffLoadedNow` to `true`, and this cause the re-rendering of your page.

Now you can use your both fetchResults.

Hope that's give you an Idea, how to solve.

Answer (score -1):

you should put the value in your div like

```
<div key={author.authorId} value={genre}>
        {author.genre}
     </div>
```

and the same for your

```
<tr key={book.id} value={(number, name)}>
```

and for the API request you can use axios